# how to check int value in the request body in django drf

Tags: python-3.x, api, django-rest-framework

basically i always used self.request.POST.get('some_param'), but here it returns none, although the objects is being created with the requested value
so the url body looks like:

```
{
    "text": "text",
    "score": 11
}
```

the prints are:

```
None
None
```

and the view for this is:

```
class ReviewViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    permission_classes = (IsAuthorOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer, **kwargs):
        title = get_object_or_404(Title, id=self.kwargs.get('title_id'))
        print(self.request.POST.get('score'))
        print(self.kwargs.get('score'))
        print(self.request.POST["score"])
        if self.request.POST.get('score') == '11' or self.request.POST.get('score') == 11:
            print('aaaaaaaaa')
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            serializer.save(title=title)
```

so im trying to prohibit the score to be above the 10
if needed the model is

```
class Review(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    #author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews', null=True, blank=True)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: `request.data['score']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access this with `request.POST`, since `request.POST` are encoded in the *headers* of the POST request.

You access the data with [**`request.data`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data):

> `request.data` returns the **parsed content of the request body**.
> (…)
> It supports REST framework's flexible request parsing, rather than just supporting form data. For example you can handle **incoming JSON** data in the same way that you handle incoming form data.

You thus can access this with:

```
request.data['score']
```

or if you do not know for sure that `score` will be passed, you can use `.get(…)`:

```
request.data.get('score')
```

Comment: thank you, that helped, also it returns a str, do you know how to make it an interg value (int() doesnt work)

Comment: @bladerunner: normally it is already an int. Exactly what does it print for `print((request.data['score'], type(request.data['score'])))`

Comment: prints `('5', <class 'str'>)`

Comment: @bladerunner: well then you should be able to work with `int(request.data['score'])`.

Comment: oh, i am sorry, an error wasnt about it, thank you very much for your help <3